# Django API throws Exception Value: Object of type ParserError is not JSON serializable, does not enter the try block

Tags: django, python-3.x

New to development of API. Any help or article would really help.
my views.py

```
@api_view(["POST"])
def retrieve_base64_as_pdf(request):
    try:
        #base_64_input = request.POST.get('ImageBase64String')
        body_unicode = request.body.decode('utf-8')
        print(len(body_unicode))
        body = json.loads(body_unicode)
        print(len(body))
        base_64_input = body['ImageBase64String']
        doc_ref_id = body['DocRefID']
        #base_64_input = json.loads(request.body["ImageBase64String"])
        pdf = base64.b64decode(base_64_input)
        #build PDF
        with open(os.path.expanduser('life/lpo-test.pdf'), 'wb') as fout:
            fout.write(pdf)
            responses = single_page_extractor(file_names='life/lpo-test.pdf',client_doc_ref_id=doc_ref_id)
            # return Response(responses, safe=False)
            return Response(responses, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)

            # responses = json.responses.replace("\'", '')
            # return Response(responses, status=status.HTTP_200_OK, content_type='json')
    except ValueError as e:
    os.remove('life/lpo-test.pdf')       
    return Response(e, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

my process,
 1. consume base 64 run my logic and output json.

```
It works 99% of the time but throws bad request at times. 
1. The json input is the same for all inputs.
```

error message:
exception: Exception Value: Object of type ParserError is not JSON serializable
The only error:
ParserError('Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected 1 fields in line 3, saw 12\n')

Answer (score 0):

Looks like `Response` class if from django-rest-framework and it will try to jsonify any input data you gave it.

On the last line you are trying to serialize error object and that's why you have a problem:

```py
return Response(e, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

Try to wrap error into `str` to make in json-serializable:

```py
return Response({'error': str(e)}, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

Also the problem might be in `single_page_extractor` if it can return error objects.

Comment: I am still facing the same error, my json doesn't even enter the try block.
{
"DocRefID":"dd4e9e5a-4f14-42b3-ac5b-5fa2432b50cc",
"ImageBase64String":"<base64>"
}

I'm really confused with this error message, could you kindly point me in the right direction

Comment: But your try block covers whole function... Can you update your question and include full stack trace of the error?

Comment: you were write it isn't entering my function. I'll create a detailed log for my function. and edit the header as soon as i figure out the issue

Comment: updating the package in middlewear solved the problem